# inserting calculated values at the end of row with values

Tags: vba, excel

My data set column is H through BQ with 3000 rows.
I have column H with values in some rows and no value in others. First,  I am trying to find the row with value. Once I do that I want to  divide that value by the corresponding value in column I to get the answer X. Finally, I then want to repeat the value in column I – X times at the end of that row which has any value

For example:

```
Row Number  Column H    Column I    Column J    Column K    Column L    
   1                                    
   2          1400        200        300            200        200              
   3                                    
   4          2000        1000                          
   5           400
```

Expected results:

**Row 2:** 
1400/200 = 7. I want to repeat the value in `Column I`(200) 7 times after `Column L`

**Row 4:**,
2000/1000 = 2. I want to repeat the value in `Column I` (1000) 2 times starting in `Column J`

**Row 5:** 400/0 = *Error*. In this case repeat the value in `Column H` (400) once in `Column I`.

Comment: ISn't row 1 blank?

Comment: Yes. my bad i meat for row 2. i will update it now

Comment: Your instructions seem off compared to the diagram. Row 2 makes sense. In row 4 you want to repeat AFTER column J or starting in Column J? Row 5 has no value in column I. Do you mean put the value of column H in Column I?

Comment: @PGCodeRider for row 4, i want to repeat STARTING in column J. Yes for row 5, i mean to put the value of column H in column I. Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should meet your requirements:

```
Sub DoThisThing()
Dim rCell As Range, OrCell As Range, startCol As Integer, dividingIntger As Integer, _
answer As Double, searchRng As Range, WS As Worksheet

Set WS = Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name) 'Or use actual sheet name i.e. Set WS = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set searchRng = WS.Range("H1:H3000") 'sets the range to search through.

For Each rCell In searchRng.Cells

    'If Column H is a numeric value, but not empty
    If IsNumeric(rCell) And Not IsEmpty(rCell) Then

        'Establishes offset cell being used
        Set OrCell = rCell.Offset(0, 1)

        'If column I has a numeric value that's not zero or blank
        If IsNumeric(OrCell) And OrCell.Value2 <> 0 Then

            'Number of columns to offset (rounded up)
            dividingIntger = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(rCell.Value2 / OrCell.Value2, 0)

            'Exact answer (decimals okay)
            answer = rCell.Value2 / dividingIntger

            'Finds which column to start entering values
            startCol = WS.Cells(rCell.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

            'sets answer value into the starting column and over (less 1)
            Range(WS.Cells(rCell.Row, startCol), WS.Cells(rCell.Row, startCol).Offset(0, dividingIntger - 1)).Value2 = answer

        'If column I is zero or blank
        ElseIf IsNumeric(OrCell) Then

            'Sets Column I = to Column H
            OrCell.Value2 = rCell.Value2

        End If

    End If

Next rCell

End Sub
 '☠☠☠☠system tested!☄⚡✨
```

Comment: i get an "overflow" error while trying to run the code

Comment: Try changing all instances of “Integer” to “Long” although with a row count of 3000 integer SHOULD do just fine.

Comment: i already tried changing the instances. "answer" is where the issue is.

Comment: @Goal7 I think this latest version should do the trick. Please accept the answer if it works for you. Thanks.

Comment: @PGCodeRider the code works great but i have a question. if i have an odd number like 1470 in column H and the value in column I is 300, the code will put 300 at the end of the string 5 times summing it to 1500. Is there anyway to modify the code to limit it to 1470?

Comment: @goal7 probably but you gotta at least mark my answer as useful. This wasn't part of your question and this is what's known as stringing people along with more requirements after they've already answered the question you supplied. I'll knock it out later when I'm at the airport bar, but explain exactly what you want in your question. Like 300, 300, 270 or something?

Comment: @PGCodeRider thank you again for your help. I just want to make sure the total amount in column H is equal to the no. of times the data repeats * the value in column I. currently this is what happens  1470(Column H)/300(column I) = ~5 time to repeat 300 starting column J.  This results in total of 1500 instead of 1470 that was in column H.  is there some how we can keep it to 1470 which would mean the data gets repeated 300,300, 300, 300, 270. Does this make sense?

Comment: @goal7 thanks for accepting the answer. It'd be easier to split evenly with 294. That work?

Comment: @PGCodeRider yes that works too as long as the sum remains the same as column H. Thank you again

Comment: @goal7 all good! So far nobody at the airport bar is remotely impressed by this code, but hopefully you drop me a `useful` tick! You have yourself a good afternoon!!